# Raydium swap appears NO DATA(Node JS)

Tags: raydium

export async function swap(amount, tokenFrom, tokenTo, fixedSide, poolInfo) {

const raydiumSwap = new RaydiumSwap();
console.log(`Raydium swap initialized`);
console.log(`Swapping ${amount} of ${tokenFrom} for ${tokenTo}...`)

const tx = await raydiumSwap.getSwapTransaction(
tokenTo,
amount,
poolInfo,
1000000,
fixedSide
);

const txid = await raydiumSwap.sendVersionedTransaction(tx, 20);

console.log(`https://solscan.io/tx/${txid}`);

};

```
async getSwapTransaction(
    toToken,
    amount,
    poolKeys,
    maxLamports = 100000,
    fixedSide = 'in'
) {
    const directionIn = poolKeys.quoteMint.toString() == toToken;
    const { minAmountOut, amountIn } = await this.calcAmountOut(poolKeys, amount, directionIn);
    const userTokenAccounts = await this.getOwnerTokenAccounts();
    const swapTransaction = await Raydium.Liquidity.makeSwapInstructionSimple({
        connection: this.connection,
        makeTxVersion: 0,
        poolKeys: {
            ...poolKeys,
        },
        userKeys: {
            tokenAccounts: userTokenAccounts,
            owner: this.wallet.publicKey,
        },
        amountIn: amountIn,
        amountOut: minAmountOut,
        fixedSide: fixedSide,
        config: {
            bypassAssociatedCheck: false,
        },
        computeBudgetConfig: {
            microLamports: maxLamports,
        },
    });

    const recentBlockhashForSwap = await this.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const instructions = swapTransaction.innerTransactions[0].instructions.filter(Boolean);

    const versionedTransaction = new VersionedTransaction(
        new TransactionMessage({
            payerKey: this.wallet.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: recentBlockhashForSwap.blockhash,
            instructions: instructions,
        }).compileToV0Message()
    );

    versionedTransaction.sign([this.wallet.payer]);

    return versionedTransaction;
}

async calcAmountOut(poolKeys, rawAmountIn, swapInDirection) {
    const poolInfo = await Raydium.Liquidity.fetchInfo({ connection: this.connection, poolKeys });

    let currencyInMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
    let currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
    let currencyOutMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
    let currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;

    if (!swapInDirection) {
        currencyInMint = poolKeys.quoteMint;
        currencyInDecimals = poolInfo.quoteDecimals;
        currencyOutMint = poolKeys.baseMint;
        currencyOutDecimals = poolInfo.baseDecimals;
    }

    const currencyIn = new Raydium.Token(currencyInMint.toBase58(), currencyInDecimals);
    const amountIn = new Raydium.TokenAmount(currencyIn, rawAmountIn * 10 ** currencyIn.decimals, false);
    const currencyOut = new Raydium.Token(currencyOutMint.toBase58(), currencyOutDecimals);
    const slippage = new Raydium.Percent(5, 100); // 5% slippage

    const { amountOut, minAmountOut, currentPrice, executionPrice, priceImpact, fee } = Raydium.Liquidity.computeAmountOut({
        poolKeys,
        poolInfo,
        amountIn,
        currencyOut,
        slippage,
    });

    return {
        amountIn,
        amountOut,
        minAmountOut,
        currentPrice,
        executionPrice,
        priceImpact,
        fee,
    };
}
```

async getOwnerTokenAccounts() {
const walletTokenAccount = await this.connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(this.wallet.publicKey, {
programId: Raydium.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
});

```
    return walletTokenAccount.value.map((i) => ({
        pubkey: i.pubkey,
        programId: i.account.owner,
        accountInfo: Raydium.SPL_ACCOUNT_LAYOUT.decode(i.account.data),
    }));
}
```

Comment: I used the above code to complete the swap, but the strange thing is that when I view the transactions on the chain, "No Data" is displayed.